# Bootstrap Table "data-data-field" attribute not working

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am defining a bootstrap table in HTML:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="/api/myapi" data-data-field="objects" data-total-field="num_results" data-side-pagination="server">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The API call is being made and JSON is getting returned:

```
{
  "num_results": 1, 
  "objects": [
    {
      "company": "My Company", 
      "create_date": "2018-07-04T06:29:06.290000", 
      "email": "test@gmail.com", 
      "id": 1, 
      "name": "Joe Bloggs"
    }
  ], 
  "page": 1, 
  "total_pages": 1
}
```

I would expect that specifying `data-data-field="objects"` would instruct Bootstrap-Table to iterate the `objects` array. Alas, it doesn't seem to work..

Any ideas?

Comment: Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/32473/

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a bug in Bootstrap-Table where it ignores dataField unless pagination is enabled. [Bug report.](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/2114)

Fixed like this:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="/api/myapi" data-data-field="objects" data-total-field="num_results" data-pagination=true data-side-pagination="server" data-id-field="id">
```